# In VBA Selenium how to target and click <a class> and return values found on the next page to spreadsheet and loop through all results?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click a  element on a page and return values found on the next page for each result on the page. The results I want from the next page is who shipped the shipment.

Here is the relevant VBA code:

```
   Dim FOrderID As Object, FOrderList As Object, FOL As Long
    FOL = 1
    t = Timer
    Do
        Set FOrderList = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[3]//div[3]//span/a")
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop While FOrderList.Count = 0
    If FOrderList.Count > 0 Then

        For Each FOrderID In FOrderList
            FOL = FOL + 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(FOL, 7) = FOrderID.Text

            .Click

            With .FindElementByXPath("//a[text()[contains(.,'Shipments')]]")
                .Click
            End With

            ActiveSheet.Cells(FOL, 8) = .FindElementById("sc14821").Text
        Next


    End If
```

Here is a pastebin link to the relevant HTML on the main page. https://pastebin.com/epFSzG8E

Also the page where I want to grab information from. 
https://pastebin.com/xBQnbQza

Please note that on the main page that the header elements also have the same a class.

Also here is the Xpath for the element I am trying to click/use: 
//[@id="sc25579"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/span/a

Comment: Is this a login based/internal URL?

Comment: Yes. I have got it set up to log into the site just fine.

Comment: And what is the error message you are getting and on which line?

Comment: I am getting run-time error '438' and it is not returning a list of OrderIds to my spreadsheet.

Comment: on which line does that occur?

Comment: It occurs on the .Click after ActiveSheet.Cells(FOL, 7) = FOrderID.Text

Comment: where is the object the .click refers to? You may need to show more of the surrounding code. Also, more of the source html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188708/discussion-between-qharr-and-daultonb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussions:

Current page you need

```
FOrderID.click
```

The click is a method of an object therefore you need to give it an object

Next page

```
.FindElementByCss(".status-history").text
```

As id is dynamic